# how to load data from an array into a uicollectionview in iOS iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Hello I have the following array.

```
arraycategories = @[@"1", @"2", @"3",
          @"4", ];
```

and I need to submit the following form

```
1    2

3    4
```

but I cannot do it or using row or selection

```
ProductsDTO * productdto = [arraycategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
cell.LabelTitle.text = productdto.name;

1     1

2     2

3     3

4     4
```

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you want to happen. You want the cell title to be the combination of two array elements? Are you guaranteed to have an array equally divisible by 2? It seems like it might be a pretty straight forward problem but I need a better explanation of what you want to happen to help you out.

Comment: Agree. Not totally clear what the intent is.

Comment: post some code with methods.....and ask proper question

Comment: Go through the link...[http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12]                                                                      And if you have any queries you can ask.